# Could not fetch the user input value at server side using React.js and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am not getting the user input value at the server side to submit in the database using `React.js and Node.js`. I am providing my code below.

**Additem.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ItemService from './ItemService';

class AddItem extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {value: ''};
        this.addItemService = new ItemService();
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
    handleChange(event){
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }
    handleSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        this.addItemService.sendData(this.state.value);
        this.props.history.push('/');
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <label>
                        Add Item:
                        <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} className="form-control"/>
                        </label><br/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" className="btn btn-primary"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default AddItem;
```

**itemService.js:**

```
import axios from 'axios';

class ItemService {

  sendData(data) {
    axios.post('http://localhost:8888/add/post', {
    item: data
  })
  .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
  }
}

export default ItemService;
```

Here from `react front end` I am sending the form data to the server which is given below.

**route/route.js:**

```
var task=require('../controller/controller.js');
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('/item',task.getUserData);
    app.post('/add/post',task.userDataSubmit);
    app.post('/edit/:id',task.userDataEdit);
    app.post('/update/:id',task.userDataUpdate);
    app.post('/delete/:id',task.userDataDelete);
}
```

**controller/controller.js**

```
var mongoJs=require('mongojs');
var dateTime = require('node-datetime');
var crypto = require("crypto");
var config=require('../config/config.js');
var database='mern-crud';
var collections=['books','items'];
var db=mongoJs(config.url+database, collections);
db.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('database connected')
});
exports.getUserData=function(req,res){
    db.items.find({},function(err,docs){
        if (!err) {
            if (docs) {
                res.json(docs);
            }
        }
    })
}
exports.userDataSubmit=function(req,res){
    console.log('req',req.body);
    var data={
        name:req.body.item
    }
    db.items.insert(data,function(err,docs){
        if (!err) {
            if (docs) {
                res.json('Item added successfully');
            }
        }else{
            res.json('unable to save to database');
        }
    })
}
exports.userDataEdit=function(req,res){

}
exports.userDataUpdate=function(req,res){

}
exports.userDataDelete=function(req,res){

}
```

My problem is after submitting the form data these are not uploaded into the database even `console.log('req',req.body);` is not executing at all. Here I need the form data should be stored into MongoDB.

Comment: Might be the CORS issue. Have you set the CORS headers from your node server?

Answer (score 0):

define the initial state of value not in the constructor, but in componentDidMount. Then use componentWillRecieveProps and componentShouldUpdate to handle your local stat updates.

Comment: @satya not sure what you mean mate?

Answer (score 0):

It might be the issue of **CORS**
The easiest way is to install node package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

```
var cors = require('cors')

var app = express()
app.use(cors())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
debugger;
```

> remember to keep you  console open when u run the application using
>   debugger keyword, otherwise it won't trigger

in your application to add a breakpoint and control the execution step by step
and see whether you get the input data to the point where the req goes to the server with neede input data. If yes then it might be cors policy

use this npm package

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())

app.get('/products/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'})
})

app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```

remember to add this in the topmost lines like shown above. that's why I have put the entire code just so that you can understand why we do it that way.
This is a middle-ware that gets added to your HTTP pipeline so u have to be well aware how to order them and what not